# Python: How do I get a list of all keys in a dictionary of dictionaries, at a given depth

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary of dictionaries, of arbitrary depth, how could I list all of the keys that are in the dictionary, at a given depth? or get a list of the keys in the dictionary and their depths?

For example, a simple dictionary would be:

```py
    dict_o_dicts = {'a': {1:'bob', 2: 'fred', 3: 'henry'},
                    'b': {2:'fred',3: 'henry', 4: 'pascale'} 
                          }
```

and I'd like a command that does something along the lines of:
`print keys_at_depth(dict_o_dicts, 0)`
would return: `['a', 'b']` and `print keys_at_depth(dict_o_dicts, 1)`
would return `[1,2,3,4]`

I can recursively walk the dictionary to find the maximum depth of the dictionary, but as soon as I try and report both the depth and the key values I end up breaking the recursion.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: The question's been answered below, but I'll make sure I provide much more details in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive approach:

```
def key_at_depth(dct, dpt):
    if dpt > 0:
        return [
            key
            for subdct in dct.itervalues()
            for key in key_at_depth(subdct, dpt - 1)
        ]
    else:
        return dct.keys()

dict_o_dicts = {
    'a': {1: 'bob', 2: 'fred', 3: 'henry'},
    'b': {2: 'fred', 3: 'henry', 4: 'pascale'},
}

key_at_depth(dict_o_dicts, 0)

Out[69]: ['a', 'b']

key_at_depth(dict_o_dicts, 1)

Out[70]: [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed, and much much cleaner than my attempts. I was starting with a depth of 0 and tried to count the depth up the the required one, and then add it to a list - counting down is much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

This routine will recursively return a `dict`ionary of `set`s of the keys at each depth:

```
def keys_by_depth(dict_, depth=0, output=None):
    if output is None:
        output = {}
    if not depth in output:
        output[depth] = set()
    for key in dict_:
        output[depth].add(key)
        if isinstance(dict_[key], dict):
            keys_by_depth(dict_[key], depth+1, output)
    return output
```

Gives the output:

```
{0: {'b', 'a'}, 1: {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

Note that this will work with a mix of dictionary and non-`dict` values at each level. For only keys at a given depth, you can call and access in one go:

```
>>> print(keys_by_depth(dict_o_dicts)[1])
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: Thanks - having a dict of the keys at different levels is useful too.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption is that, all levels have valid `dicts`

```
dict_o_dicts = {'a': {1:'bob', 2: 'fred', 3: 'henry'},
                'b': {2:'fred',3: 'henry', 4: 'pascale'} }
from itertools import chain
def keys_at_depth(d, l):
    if l == 0: return d.keys()
    elif l > 0: return set(chain.from_iterable([keys_at_depth(d[k], l - 1) for k in d]))

print keys_at_depth(dict_o_dicts, 1)
```

**Output**

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are working with a tree structure and you want obtain the nodes given a level. Reading your post, I realized may exists more dictionaries at the same level. So the solution I post here returns all the keys of all dictionaries at the given level.

```
keys=[]
def keys_at_level(tree, level):
    # TODO: Eliminate that ugly global var keys.
    if level == 0:     # Adjust this contition to your needs (0 or 1)
        # Calculate keys.
        global keys
        keys.extend(tree.keys())
    else:
        # Iter throught values and ask for dicts.
        values  =  tree.values()
        for value in values:
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                keys_at_level(value, level-1)


keys_at_level(tree, 0)
print keys
# If you don't want duplicates just do:
keys = set(keys)
```